# Install DXA 2.0 Resolver on the Publisher machine?

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

We have a separate Publisher and CMS machine.  While installing DXA 2.0, we are [installing the Resolver](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v10&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-B2394627-794C-4AF0-BDF3-C5B3A5398327&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-8B8C6D9E-365E-4C2D-90FD-C4BDFA8B12B2.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-B2394627-794C-4AF0-BDF3-C5B3A5398327&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20DXA-v10%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dcms%255C-customresolver.ps1%2520&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1529623070388&currentQuery=cms%255C-customresolver.ps1%2520&currentScope=) using the command `.\cms-customresolver.ps1`.  (btw, while running with  .\cms-customresolver.ps1 -distDestination "C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web" we got an error 'A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'distDestination'')

It worked fine on the CMS, but at the end it gave us an error that it could not restart the Publisher service (we have it disabled on the CMS, since we have a separate Publisher box).

Do we need to install it again on the Publisher machine?  Do we still need to have it installed on the CMS (that doesn't have a Publisher)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, Resolvers are used by the Publisher Service to resolve a publish action on a source item into zero or more items to be rendered.

So, yes, custom Resolvers should be installed on all Publisher boxes.

Resolvers are also used by the CME if the user presses the “See items to publish” button on the Publish Dialog.  So, you should also install those on CME boxes.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to look like documentation reference parameter was wrong.

**Correct Command:**

```
.\cms-customresolver.ps1 -extensionTargetFolder DxaExtensionPath -cmSiteName SITENAME
```

Eg:

```
 .\cms-customresolver.ps1 -extensionTargetFolder "C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\web\WebUI" -cmSiteName "SDL Web"
```

cms-customresolver script adds the DXA Custom Resolver to the CMS/Publishing server's GAC and modifies the **Tridion.ContentManager.config** (suitable for R2 mapping only)

Indeed, Rick already answered, yes we need to install all the CME and Publishers servers.

Comment: Please create a comment on the documentation topic for this documentation defect.

Comment: Yes. I did already

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn’t even check. :-)